# Null Reference Exception.....but the value is NOT NULL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nullreferenceexception

I have a line of code `string managerFirstName = "test@test.com";` that is flagging as NULL. How is this NULL....its a string that is populated when its created....is there an error with my VS2013? or a setting I need to change?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try a rebuild. Sometimes the debugger gets confused which source code line the exception is on.

Comment: I tried a clean and rebuild and even restarted my cpu

Comment: Is it that managerUser null? rather than managerFirstName?

Comment: Please post the detailed call stack from `View Detail ...`

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. A project or solution "clean" does not actually clean out all the compiled dll's fand pdb's rom the bin/obj Debug directories. After deleting the bin and obj directories through file explorer then doing a rebuild, my debugger properly showed the source and related it to the error.

Comment: @G_S it is managerFirstName

Comment: @Paurian thanks for that but it didnt not resolve the issue

Comment: @IanMercer please see updated Q

Comment: Are you doing a Debug build or a Release build?

Comment: @Vilx- debug   ...

Comment: Did you delete ALL bin/obj folders in the solution, not just for this project?

Comment: Use `var`,`String` or `object`. Look for a change?

Comment: @superstator yes iv deleted the bin folder for every project in the solution

Comment: If you can't get it to clean/build properly, you can try to fix the null reference. It will likely be on a line near the one that is highlighted. That `ADUser managerUser` line above the highlighted line could be it, for example. Has it got a semicolon at the end? Maybe it is running on to the highlighted line.

Comment: And the obj folders? Do you have custom output folders set for any projects? Can you build each project individually and verify it recreates the bin/obj folders with new files?

Comment: @superstator iv done what you suggested removing obv and bin folders from every project, and also tried a fresh pull from repo and its still happening...very frustrating...its not a code issue surely

Comment: @sss the project is building fine, it just crashes when it hits that line

Comment: Only three options I can see: you still have a stale PDB somewhere, some kind of deferred execution is happening and raising an exception here that was actually thrown earlier (are you using IQueryable?), or you have mixed up debug settings and your Debug build is being optimized and mangling things.

Comment: @superstator well is there anyway to reset these settings? without having to uninstall and reinstall vs? and its happening for vs 13, 15 and 17 so maybe a re install wouldnt fix it

Comment: They are in the .csproj. Make sure code optimization is turned off for Debug builds.

Comment: Though this suggestion won't address why your debugger lines are off, to fix the exception you might try to let it stop your code, and while in the debugger use the QuickWatch functionality to sniff out if coreData or newUser or managerUser are null. It really sounds like your pdb files are out of sync. Also, if you have breakpoints, but when running it warns that they won't be hit because the code differs, it's an indication that the dll's aren't matching up to the code. Just knowing your issue is half the battle but sometimes you have to skip the fight and just fix the code.

Comment: I just noticed that you're using DotNetNuke. What version? Some versions have had issues with AD extensions. See http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/89/scope/threads and do a google on NullReferenceException DotNetNuke ActiveDirectorySynchronize ... there might be something within those forums that will provide you a lead. ... but please let us know if you figure out why your debugger is throwing an exception on the line you highlighted once you figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's not the highlighted line that is crashing - the IDE is highlighting the wrong line.

The stack trace you posted mentions `RFS.DotNetNuke.Service.ActiveDirectorySynchronise.something`. Try and look for a line of code that uses that object - probably the line of code above the highlighted line (`GetManagerForOrgUnit`). Examine each of the parameters for that call and see if you can find a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is code related, not build, this looks like a threading issue. Try wrapping the whole function in a lock, and looking for how contexts could be getting mangled.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue with VS 2022. Where this happens I get null reference and errors. I have found that this was because my debug configuration was set to Release and not debug.

[image]

Comment: This is what happened to me as well. Because of the different configuration, the debugger pointed to the wrong line where nothing was `null`

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing Visual Studio component cache.

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager) Delete the directory:

   ```
   %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
   ```
2. Restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

This used to happen to me in VS2k13 a lot. Basically your code is not getting rebuilt. Even after a clean/rebuild, some code refuses to compile. What used to work for me was1. Clean/rebuild. 2. Make a code change in the area of code you are looking at. 3. Put a breakpoint in the calling method. 4. Debug and f11 step line by line to your code change.

Comment: thank you for the reply but that did not work, same issue happening for VS 13,15 and 17

Comment: Try to comment out any later references to the variable, or if they are linq operations then change them to non linq, and see if that helps. Change the text content to 'abc' too. Just to explore.

Comment: Try switching debug view to IL and see what is null.

Comment: One more... Check if this is a threading issue. Put a lock around the code

Answer (score 0):

Would just like to say thank you to everyone who helped me out with this Q....I found the cause...just above the

```
ADUser managerUser = GetManagerNameForOrgUnit(coreData.OrgAssignment_0001.OrgUnit.ID, coreData.PersonnelNo);
```

there is an if statement, which during testing always stops the code from hitting GetManagerNameForOrgUnit(), I have been manually stepping over this if.

I commented it out and the code works fine.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I was manually skipping execution of few lines (apparently unrelated code section).